# Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,) throw exception Unable to establish connection on channel. Flutter + Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-dependencies

Hello I am using flutter + firebase and when I call the **Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,)** function in the main() function the

> `Unable to establish connection on channel.`

exception is thrown.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pas your other information also like this

```
options: FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: "XXX",
      appId: "XXX",
      messagingSenderId: "XXX",
      projectId: "XXX",
    )
```

and flutter clean then flutter pub get then run it